# Assassination in an office (again)

Tags: cipher, mystery

*<sub>Inspired by a puzzle posted not that long ago.</sub>*

A man was killed in an office. We have five suspects:

> Isaac - takes care of trash in the company
>
> Caleb - he once stole two dollars from a colleague's cabinet
>
> Nathan - was once caught torrenting at work
>
> David - takes care of IT stuff (he's a weirdo, by the way)
>
> Gabriel - well, picked just to have five suspects

As you can clearly see, their roles doesn't matter. What matters is the note that was found on the crime scene:

> **"IISAC 14202410212202211102311"**

So, who killed him?

I'm giving a hint:

> Nothing separates the letters.

IISAC thing hint:

> If I took the letters, and rearranged them a bit...

Comment: Downvote for anti-climatic story, or same idea? ^^

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Don't mind the downvotes. you do you. (+1)

Comment: As you can see from style of my comment, I don't really care :P And that's my first puzzle here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, looks much better now (y)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any of the usual ciphers

Comment: hmmmm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAAC_(cipher)

Comment: To be honest, I am not that sure if it should be under "cipher" section. But still, answer is pretty simple. It took me literally 15 minutes to come up with idea, find needed info and write it here.

Comment: @MiquelColl NONONONO, that's not it XD But at least I learned that something like ISAAC exists XD

Comment: @Xirate Yeah, that definitely counts as a cipher.

Comment: Another question where the [similar logos](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/is-the-puzzling-icon-too-similar-to-ours) of The Workplace and Puzzling make things interesting in the HNQ.

Comment: The man had all the time to write this cipher while he was dying xD But then killed could have deleted all this, (s)he thought of it as gibberish and decided not to.

Comment: Did anyone else find this link amusing because it might look like it's [an actual office murder mystery](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think, it's

> Caleb

The numbers

> separated by 0 (nothing) are
>  142, 241, 2122, 22111, 2311

should be decoded as

> alternating 1s and 0s, their numbers given by the strings above
>  1000011 (1 times 1 followed by 4 times 0 followed by 2 times 1, hence 142), 1100001, 1101100, 1100101, 1100010

which is

> ASCII (anagram of IISAC) codes for Caleb

Comment: You sure about this? :P

Comment: You sir deserve a cookie :P And I like how your nickname suits my character naming convention :D

Comment: @Xirate sounds like you found suspect #6

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer in case it's helpful to other people. Still working on it :)

**IISAC**:

> I got nothing on this yet.

**14202410212202211102311**:

> Splitting this on the zeroes gives 5 substrings:
>  142 - 241 - 2122 - 22111 - 2311
>  All 5 of the subgroups have digits which add up to 7.
>
>  This suggests the answer is more likely to be a 5-letter name, which would be Isaac, Caleb or David, but that's just a guess at this point.
>
>   Based on the hint, which I've just seen, "nothing" separates the letters. This confirms that the subgroups are letters, separated by the zeroes, so we're talking a 5-letter name.

Comment: Really close :)

Comment: "nothing" thing confirmed :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> David

Because the clue

> spells out Caleb in ASCII, as elias mentioned.

However

> I'm kinda suspicious that either a) the guy killed had enough time to encode and transcribe the clue before being killed, and/or b) that the killer left or allowed the clue to be left when it leads back to him.  Doesn't seem likely.  Even if the killer didn't know what it said, it was typed after the killed guy knoew he was going to be murdered - the killer should have *known* it was dangerous to leave, obviously!

Therefore

> David, the weirdo, becomes my suspect, because he does "IT" stuff - which might include ASCII, coding, and so is likely to be *creating* the clue.  None of the other suspects has as good a connection with the code (though Nathan, who torrented, came close - but I don't think torrenting requires ASCII). Caleb, who stole two dollars, is being framed (possibly the two dollars belonged to David).  David left the clue to point the finger at someone else!

Comment: Dude, made my day.

Answer (score 4):

It is :

> Gabriel

Numbers show all 7 , and he is the only one with 7 letters in his name.

Comment: Nope. Sorryyy :)

Comment: A good approach! :)